# Обновление системных корневых сертификатов

Tags: winapi, openssl

Я извлекаю корневые сертификаты при помощи функции CertEnumCertificatesInStore() из хранилищ ROOT и CA, чтобы создать из них список для OpenSSL. Проблема в том, что для разных пользователей (используется домен AD) этот список разный. Даже на одном компьютере. Т.е. под одним пользователем OpenSSL может не установить соединение с сайтом, потому что его сертификат не проходит проверку, а под другим - может. И соответственно под первым извлекается меньше сертификатов, а под другим - больше. Но если под первым пользователем запустить Internet Explorer, то с этого момента под ним из хранилищ вытаскивается столько же сертификатов, сколько и для второго пользователя и ssl соединение с сайтом устанавливается.

Поскольку я пишу службу, мне не нравится идея, указывать в документации что-то, типа "вы должны периодически входить в систему под этим пользователем и запускать Internet Explorer". Как мне сделать то же самое самому, попросить windows обновить список корневых сертификатов для текущего пользователя? И желательно правильный способ, а не какой-нибудь костыль, в стиле "ну ты там просто запускай Internet Explorer из службы".

Comment: А известно почему ie подтягивает новые сертификаты? Откуда он их добывает?

Comment: Если бы я знал - не задавал бы этот вопрос. :) Просто бился пару дней как рыба об лёд, почему под моей учётной записью программа работает, а под созданной для использования - нет. В отчаянии я вошёл под ней и запустил Internet Explorer, чтобы проверить не заблокировано ли соединение каким-нибудь фаерволом. Но всё работало. И тут программа начала работать. Потом это было проверено не некоторых других компьютерах в сети. Вход в систему и запуск Internet Explorer исправляет ситуацию.

Comment: может Wireshark'ом посмотреть что он делает?

Comment: Посмотреть-то можно, только это мне ничего не даст. Я надеюсь, что он использует какое-то документированное api, которое делает эту работу. Потому что качать их вручную - тот же костыль, который будет работать пока ms не сменит серверы.